# Why does this Qt signal never get emitted?

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to get data out of a web page, but the signal `finished()` never gets emitted!!! I know I must be doing something wrong, but can't figure out what it is.

```
# webservice.h
class WebService:public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

 public:
    explicit WebService(QObject *parent=0);
    void getRequest(const QString &urlString);

signals:
    void networkError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError ne);
    void finished(QNetworkReply*);

public slots:
    void parseNetworkResponse(QNetworkReply* finished);

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager *netMgr;

public:
    QByteArray data;
};

#webservice.cpp
WebService::WebService(QObject *parent):QObject(parent)
{
    netMgr = new QNetworkAccessManager;

    connect(netMgr, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
                 this, SLOT(parseNetworkResponse(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void WebService::getRequest(const QString &urlString)
{
    QUrl url(urlString);
    QNetworkRequest req;
    emit finished(netMgr->get(req));
}

void WebService::parseNetworkResponse(QNetworkReply *finished)
{
    if (finished->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        emit networkError(finished->error());
        return;
    }

    data = finished->readAll();

   qDebug() << data;
}
```

`data` never gets assigned a value as expected.

Comment: How are you using `WebService`? Can you show the code that calls the `WebService` methods?

Comment: Also connect to the error() signal to catch errors properly

Answer (score 1):

You aren't passing the url to the `QNetworkRequest` you create. Try:

```
QNetworkRequest req(url);
```

inside `WebService::getRequest()`.

---

As requested, here's the source modified to allow it compile and work inside QtCreator as a single `main.cpp` file in a console application project:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QString>

#include <QDebug>

//# webservice.h
class WebService:public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

 public:
    explicit WebService(QObject *parent=0);
    void getRequest(const QString &urlString);

signals:
    void networkError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError ne);
    void finished(QNetworkReply*);

public slots:
    void parseNetworkResponse(QNetworkReply* finished);

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager *netMgr;

public:
    QByteArray data;
};

//#webservice.cpp
WebService::WebService(QObject *parent):QObject(parent)
{
    netMgr = new QNetworkAccessManager;

    connect(netMgr, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
                 this, SLOT(parseNetworkResponse(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void WebService::getRequest(const QString &urlString)
{
    QUrl url(urlString);
    QNetworkRequest req(url);
    emit finished(netMgr->get(req));
}

void WebService::parseNetworkResponse(QNetworkReply *finished)
{
    if (finished->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        qDebug() << "QNetworkReply error: " << finished->error();
        emit networkError(finished->error());
        return;
    }

    data = finished->readAll();

   qDebug() << data;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    WebService web;
    web.getRequest("http://www.google.com");

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

The minor modifications that were made:

- added necessary headers
- added a `main()` that called `WebService::getRequest()` with an appropriate URL
- added `#include "main.moc"` to the end of the `main.cpp` file so qmake would "moc-ify" it properly as a single, self-contained .cpp file
- made the fix mentioned above in the answer to the question
- added a `qDebug()` output in the error case

One final thing that needed to be done was to add `QT += network` in the .pro file for the project so the Qt networking modules get added to the link step and to the header search path.

---

Update 15 Oct 2013

From your comments, it looks like you want the `QNetworkAccessManager::get()` call to be synchronous.  I've added another version of your example program that will block in `WebService::getRequest()` until the request's `finished` signal is received.  Note that this example doesn't perform much in the way of error handling, and would probably perform very badly if the netwrok request fails to complete in a timely manner. Dealing apprpriately with errors and timeouts would be necessary for anything but example or study code.

The basic idea in this example is that the signals emitted in the asynchronous Qt networking model are driven by the framework's event loop.  So when a request is made, a new 'nested' event loop is created and the `WebService::getRequest()` function execs that loop (and stays there) until the handler of the `finished` signal tells the event loop to exit.

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QUrl>

#include <QEventLoop>

#include <QByteArray>
#include <QString>

#include <QDebug>

//# webservice.h


class WebService:public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

 public:
    explicit WebService(QObject *parent=0);
    void getRequest(const QString &urlString);

signals:
    void networkError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError ne);
    //void finished(QNetworkReply*);

public slots:
    void parseNetworkResponse(QNetworkReply* finished);

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager *netMgr;
    QEventLoop request_event_loop;

public:
    QByteArray data;
};

//#webservice.cpp
WebService::WebService(QObject *parent):QObject(parent)
{
    netMgr = new QNetworkAccessManager;

    connect(netMgr, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
                 this, SLOT(parseNetworkResponse(QNetworkReply*)));
}

void WebService::getRequest(const QString &urlString)
{
    QUrl url(urlString);
    QNetworkRequest req(url);
    netMgr->get(req);

    request_event_loop.exec();        // wait here until the WebService::parseNetworkResponse() slot runs
    // emit finished(netMgr->get(req));
}

void WebService::parseNetworkResponse(QNetworkReply *finished)
{
    qDebug() << "enter parseNetworkResponse()";

    if (finished->error() != QNetworkReply::NoError)
    {
        qDebug() << "QNetworkReply error: " << finished->error();
        emit networkError(finished->error());
    }
    else {
        data = finished->readAll();

        qDebug() << data;
    }

    qDebug() << "request_event_loop.exit()";
    request_event_loop.exit();
    qDebug() << "exit parseNetworkResponse()";
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    WebService web;

    qDebug() << "main() getRequest()";
    web.getRequest("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
    qDebug() << "main() getRequest() completed";

    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: Maybe you can explain more about what the main issue is (or post a complete, compilable example). If I make the modification mentioned in the answer, I get a response out of `finished->readAll();`. Assuming, of course, that the `urlString` is valid (I used `"http://www.google.com"` in my test).

Comment: Thanks Michael, The issue is exactly this.  I did try to compile my program with the "http://www.google.com" too.  and it did not produce any output for the QByteArray data variable. The above program compiles with no error, and I don't get the data variable to output anything.  Both my url and yours are definitely valid urls. I don't know what to say!!!  except to find out the solution.  if and only if the above codes are incorrect.

Comment: Two things: 1) without the `"http://"` prefix on the url the request results in a `QNetworkReply::ProtocolUnknownError` error, and 2) you might need to disable a firewall on the machine to allow the request to work.  When I went home and tried this again, the application hung on the request until I disabled the firewall software on the machine.

Comment: Could you please send me the example code you've compiled? cause I have tried everything you have said and recommended.  btw: I do not have a firewall.

Comment: Thanks Michael for everything.  A Big thumb for you.

Comment: It appears to me that qDebug() << web.data; gets processed before the call to web.getRequest("http://www.google.com"); eventhough, I have coded web.data after the web.getRequest("http://www.google.com").

Comment: @user1787326: are you talking about adding a `qDebug() << web.data;` immediately after the `getRequest()` call in `main()`?  If so, then the problem is that `web.getRequest()` doesn't block - you can't read the reply until the `QNetworkReply` object has finished (at which point it emits the `finished` signal that ultimately results in `parseNetworkResponse()` getting called).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  So What do I have to do in order to make use of QByteArray data outside of the parseNetworkResonse() method?

Comment: Well, that's what the `finished` signal is for.  You can create a slot for wherever you do want to read the data and connect the `finished` signal to it (I thought that that was what `parseNetworkResponse()` was for).  Exactly how else you might want to wait for the data to be ready depends a lot on the specifics of what it is you'll ultimately want to do.  But at the bottom of it will (or should) be a slot that's connected to the `finished` signal.

Comment: See, What I had in mind was to save the value of finish->readAll() to variable data which is public, and then use the data variable in another method as in following example:

Comment: getThumbnails(const QString &VideoID )
{
    QString url = "http://i1.ytimg.com/vi/" + VideoID + "/default.jpg";

    QImage *img = new QImage();
    img->loadFromData(this->Data());
    ...

    return this->Data();
}

Comment: I hope this is my final comment!  No Sir,  That is not what I had in mind, cause after trying your update code, the class variable does not retain the same value as it has inside the method parseNetworkResponse().  Would you please try doing this in main? do a  qDebug() << web.data; in the main method. you will notice that data has no value, and only has a reasonable value inside the parseNetworkResponse() method.

Comment: I added `qDebug() << web.data;` just before the return statement in `main()` and it output the same string as it did inside `parseNetworkResponse()`.  I don't know why it would be different for you.

Comment: this is the output I am getting:

Comment: "" 
request_event_loop.exit() 
exit onRequestCompleted()

Comment: If there's nothing between the quotes before the `request_event_loop.exit()` line, then the request didn't return any data.  You have a problem with the URL or some other networking problem. Are you testing with the `"http://www.stackoverflow.com"` URL?  That returns a relatively short bit of HTML that says that the document has moved.

Comment: It's rather ridiculous.  I became bold pulling my hairs.  I'm using Qt 5.1 and for IDE I'm using Qt-Creator.  Would these have anything to do with it?

Comment: I have tested it both with linux and Windows, yielding the same issue.

Comment: I've tried this on a Win7 system with Qt 5.0.2 (MinGW)/QtCreator 2.7.0, another Win7 system with Qt 5.1.1 (MSVC 2012)/QtCreator 2.8.1, and just installed Qt 5.1.1/Qt 2.8.1 on a 32-bit Ubuntu. All three set-ups worked as expected, outputting the small snippet of HTML from `http://www.stackoverflow.com` and storing it in the `WebService::data` member variable.  Are you copy/pasting the code from the answer? I'm not sure what else I can do.

Comment: @user1787326: it might be nice to let us know what the solution was.

Comment: 1- was <QtCore/QCoreApplication>

Comment: 2- was I kept missing to write request_event_loop.exec()

Comment: Ah, yes - the `request_event_loop.exec()` is critical to making this work synchronously.  Sorry that I didn't call that out more clearly.  Glad you got things working.

Comment: One more Michael, Please direct me on how to use QJsonDocument on ubuntu linux.  I cannot find the header.  The only I found is <QJson/parser.h>

Comment: I don't really know anything about `QJsonDocument`. A quick search shows the header in `include/QtCore`. You'll need Qt 5.0 or later.

Comment: Again, Thank you Michael.